# Facebook integration: Link to local site profile page?

Tags: php, facebook, api

I need to make a small membership website, where users can leave comments on some articles. For that purpose I want to use Facebook comments plugin. But the problem is that from the comments, the user name is linked to his facebook profile, and I would like to link it to the local profile page. For example instead of link to facebook.com/username i will like to connect to mysite.com/username.
Is there any possiblity to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't tweak anything about the Facebook comments widget. If you want that, you'll need to implement your own commenting system.

Comment: True, he cant change widget but there's solution... it's possible to get complete comments-content from graph api ... something like fb shows in [this example](https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments) `comments->data->from->name` (or `->id`). He must make connection between facebook ID and and profiles on his website. It's easy to extract "message" & user "id" and w/ bit of coding and bit of style make output.

Comment: Sure, but then you'd have to display all the comments manually, deal with caching the data, and you'd have all the comments duplicated when you display the widget too. Not a good solution at all.

Comment: Totally agree, that's terrible solution. But here's idea, not the best one but still... to put widget inside scrollable javascript div (overflow:hidden; height of comment box), scroll it at the bottom and show just comment-box. Bottom of line, he can hide comments from widget (i haven't tried that but guess it's possible) ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you know any other comments hosting service which offers such possibility?

Answer (score 0):

How about a wordpress site with a Buddypress option? Read more at http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/buddypress/